# Azure AD C2C/Next.Js/ASP.NET Core 6: How to use PKCE auth code flow access tokens to access Web API?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, next.js, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I need help, I got stuck for a few days trying to protect a **Web API (ASP.NET Core 6)** by sending **access token** from users (**Azure Ad B2C** with **google provider/local account**) signed in with **authentication code flow (PKCE)**.

This generates a (401) unauthorized error. What is going wrong?

### The Next.js Application: (helloworld.webapp)

---

#### Azure Ad B2C settings

**Manage -> Authentication**

**Single-page-application** with **redirect uri: http://localhost:3000**

**Manage -> API permissions**

**helloworld.api**
access_as_user  | admin consent required: yes | status:  ✅ Granted for helloworld

**Microsoft Graph**
offline_access | admin consent required: yes | status:  ✅ Granted for helloworld
openid | admin consent required: yes | status:  ✅ Granted for helloworld

(unchecked)
 Access tokens (used for implicit flows)
 ID tokens (used for implicit and hybrid flows)

---

This is how you **log in**.

```
  const login = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    console.log("only logs in browser console")
    instance.loginRedirect({ 
       scopes: [
     "openid", 
     "offline_access", 
      // ✅ checked for typo
     "https://helloworld.onmicrosoft.com/8a1bc000-2000-4000-a000-d3156a663000/access_as_user", 
     ]
   }) 
 }
```

In the following snippet you can see how I get my **accessToken**.

```
const postData = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    // to prevent ssr mismatch errors. 
    if (!data && inProgress === InteractionStatus.None) {
      instance
        .acquireTokenSilent({
       scopes: [
     "openid", 
     "offline_access", 
     // ✅ checked for typo
     "https://helloworld.onmicrosoft.com/8a1bc000-2000-4000-a000-d3156a663000/access_as_user",
     ]
        })
        .then((accessTokenResponse) => {
          let accesstoken = accessTokenResponse.accessToken;
         
          console.log(accesstoken); // only logs in browser console.
          // // ✅ weatherforecast endpoint checked. Maps to http://localhost:5015/api/:path*
          fetch("/api/net/weatherforecast", {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${JSON.stringify(accesstoken)}`,
            },
          })
            .then((res) => console.log(res))
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));
        });
    }
  };
```

I have the following rule in `next.config.js`

```
  async rewrites() {
    return {
      fallback: [
        {
          source: "/api/net/:path*",
          destination: "http://localhost:5015/api/:path*",
        },
      ],
    };
  },
```

---

### ASP.NET Core 6 application: (helloworld.api)

---

**manage -> expose API**

**scopes** ✅ all checked for typo
https://helloworld.onmicrosoft.com/8a1bc000-2000-4000-a000-d3156a663000/access_as_user
Who can consent: Admins only
State: Enabled

---

The `appsettings.json`

```cs
  "AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://helloworld.b2clogin.com/",
    "ClientId": "8a1bc000-2000-4000-a000-d3156a663000",
    "Domain": "helloworld.onmicrosoft.com",
    "Scopes": "access_as_user",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_authflow"
  },
```

The `Program.cs` generated with `dotnet new webapi -au IndividualB2C` with added `cors`.

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C"));

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("default", builder =>
 {
     builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
             .AllowAnyMethod()
             .AllowAnyHeader();
 }));

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
else
{
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
}


app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

The `WeatherForecastController`

```cs
[Authorize]
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[RequiredScope(RequiredScopesConfigurationKey = "AzureAd:Scopes")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

    private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

    public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        })
        .ToArray();
    }
}
```

And lastly, the **user flow**

### User Flow (B2C_1_authflow)

[image]

**Possible causes?:**

no https as this gave a net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

```
else
{
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
}
```

Some problem because next.js is a full-stack application? I believe it acts as SPA as I delay the acquiring accessToken untill InteractionStatus.None?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you need to modify the way of provisioning scope in app settings. Try giving complete scope  `https://<tenant>/api/<scope>.`

```
{
"AzureAdB2C": {
  "Instance": "https://<your-tenant-name>.b2clogin.com",
  "ClientId": "<web-app-application-id>",
  "Domain": "<your-b2c-domain>",
  "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "<your-sign-up-in-policy>"
       // "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout/<your-sign-up-in-policy>",
},
"TodoList": {
    "TodoListScope": "https://contoso.onmicrosoft.com/api/access_as_user openid offline_access",
    "TodoListBaseAddress": "https://localhost:44332"
  }
```

}

- Also check if app.UseHttpsRedirection(); is to be used after if loop

  ```
   if (env.IsDevelopment())
           {
               app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

           app.UseHttpsRedirection();

           app.UseRouting();

           app.UseAuthentication();
           app.UseAuthorization();
  ```

Also please make sure to recheck and give  proper redirect url , which has to be same in portal and authorization request. It has to be [valid url](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reply-url)

Reference:
[Configure authentication in a sample web application that calls a web API by using Azure Active Directory B2C | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-authentication-sample-web-app-with-api?tabs=visual-studio#step-5-configure-the-sample-web-app)